# Does anyone know where I can find a bike template or mockup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, resource-recommendations

I'm working on a school project about a fake campus bike rental company and I'm trying to create mockups of everything but I can't seem to find any customizable bicycle templates or mockup photoshop files of any bike racks. If anyone knows where I can find some, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out www.graphicriver.com

I found a couple bike templates that might work for you there, though you will probably be better off trying to create your own.

http://graphicriver.net/item/realistic-bike-mock-up/8012834?WT.oss_phrase=Bike%20mock&WT.oss_rank=2&WT.z_author=zlatkosan1&WT.ac=search_thumb